# C# - I try to connect my Database to DataGridView in form but there's an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

i'm new to C# programming and have been following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ2QjRr3toM

I am using C# and SQL Server.
I'm trying to make my [User] table to show up on the datagridview.

---

Form Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Software
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

SQLFunction Class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Software
{
    static class SQLFunctions
    {
        static private SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Software.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString");

        static public void Refresh(DataGridView _dataGridView)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECCT * FROM [User]", connection);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                _dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
            catch(SqlCeException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Software.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

**My problem is that when I try to run my program, I get an error saying my SQLFunctions class threw an exception.**

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
    Message = "The type initializer for 'Software.SQLFunctions' threw an exception."
    Source = Software
    TypeName = Software.SQLFunctions
    StackTrace:
       at Software.SQLFunctions.Refresh(DataGridView _dataGridView)
       at Software.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\misaru02\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Thesis\Software\frmUserMgmt.cs:line 22
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    InnerException:
       Message = "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."
       Source = System.Data
       StackTrace:
          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
          at Software.SQLFunctions..cctor() in c:\Users\misaru02\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Thesis\Software\SQLFunctions.cs:line 16
```

---

How can I solve this error? I have followed the steps in the tutorial. :(
Please help as this is my thesis and I only have limited time :'(

Comment: are you using SQL server compact edition?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I tell?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your connection string.

You'll notice in the InnerException, there is a message stating

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

The trace leading to this exception leads me to believe the connection string is at fault here.

There may be a typo or quotation issue at fault.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a hardcoded string in your constructor in the very first line. You need to get the value from your config file, not pass in the string value of the config entry.

```
static private SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Software.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

You might also look at your select statement, the keyword select is misspelled.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried what you said and also corrected my Select statement but I still get an error with the InnerException message as "Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'."

Comment: That's because you still have gibberish in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

From the connection string it looks like you are not using SQL Server CE. That being said you should be using `SqlConnection` not `SqlCeConnection` .

```
static class SQLFunctions
{
    static private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Software.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString");

    static public void Refresh(DataGridView _dataGridView)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [User]", connection);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            _dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
        catch(SqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

*Also 'SELECT` in your query was misspelled.

EDIT:

Don't hardcode your connectionstring.

```
static private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Software.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ToString()););
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that and corrected my Select statement but I still get an error with the InnerException message as "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."